# $n$th-order Hadamard power (or root) of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors, hadamard-product

I am familiar with the notation of the [$n$th-order Hadamard power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations)
$$
\mathbf{A}^{\circ n}
$$
or root
$$
\mathbf{A}^{\circ \frac{1}{n}}
$$

I wonder if it is sensible to use this notation for vectors as well, that is,
$$
\mathbf{v}^{\circ n} = (v_1^n, v_2^n, \dots, v_N^n)
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{v}^{\circ \frac{1}{n}} = \left(\sqrt[n]{v_1}, \sqrt[n]{v_2}, \dots, \sqrt[n]{v_N}\right)
$$

Comment: Vectors *are* matrices.

Comment: @AnneBauval No. Vectors are a numerical entity in a $n$-dimensional space. A matrix is a linear transformation. They have different concepts.

Comment: No, a matrix is definitely  not a linear transformation. An $m\times n$ matrix is "a numerical entity in an $mn$-dimensional space" and (column) vectors are $m\times1$ matrices.

Comment: @AnneBauval Wrong. [Chapter 7](http://students.aiu.edu/submissions/profiles/resources/onlineBook/Y5B7M4_Introduction_to_Linear_Algebra-_Fourth_Edition.pdf), good reading.

Comment: Lol Good reading yourself (of that chapter, or an equivalent one in *any* book about linear algebra). You seem to confuse linear transformations and their matrices in given basis.

Comment: @AnneBauval Well, I just tried to help you, but you either did not read (possibly) or read and refused to accept it. Ok, I did my part.

Comment: It seems *you* needed (and still possibly need) help. I answered your question and I am ready to answer other ones if necessary.

Comment: @AnneBauval "their matrices in given basis." That is right, a matrix can change in a given basis. But you are missing the real point: If $T\left\{\cdot\right\}$ is a linear transformation and $\mathbf{x}$ is the input vector, then there exists $\mathbf{A}$ such that $T\left\{\mathbf{x}\right\} = \mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{y}$. That is what I am trying to make you understand: A matrix is a mathematical writing of a linear transformation. If you are uncertain about it, you can really read my reference and convince yourself :)

Comment: @AnneBauval more precisely, sec 7.2 can help you :)

Comment: Yes , thankfully I know at least one place where this has been used. It's been defined for matrices, then liberally used for vectors as well where necessary.

Comment: Attaching the source [here](http://www.math.iisc.ac.in/~khare/teaching/Math341-notes.pdf) for my previous comment : see Definition 3.6, and just above it.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer thank you for the reference. Yes, AFAIK Hadamard product are also called Schur product.

Comment: I didn't answer this question because I wasn't sure that the notation was standard : I haven't seen enough sources to confirm this. The papers of Fitzgerald, Horn, Jain etc. given in the document should contain the standard notation, and I wouldn't be surprised if it is the one you introduce.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Regarding notations, I've already seen some differences among the authors. Not big deal. If you are up to answer it, fell free.

Comment: @RubemPacelli Unfortunately, I don't have the time, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, since your (row) vector
$$\mathbf v= (v_1,v_2,\dots, v_N)$$
is nothing more than a particular case of a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) $A$ (with one row and $N$ columns).

Hadamard product, which you are "familiar with", deals with matrices (not linear transformations ;-) ), [in particular with row or column matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9166/is-there-an-existing-name-for-piecewise-vector-multiplication).

Comment: $v= (v_1,v_2,\dots, v_N)$ is not a row vector. It is just an alternative for $\mathbf{v} = \left[v_1, v_2. \dots, v_n\right]^\top$, which some authors adopt it. But, although partially wrong, I see your point. Thank you.

Comment: It *is* both a row vector and the transpose of a column vector. And my answer is neither a "point" nor "partially wrong". Good luck! *You* probably downvoted it (after someone else upvoted it). May it have given you some pleasure ;-)

Comment: $\mathbf{v} = \left[v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\right]^\top$ gives vector (defined as a column). That is elementary...

Comment: One more small mistake. Better have a rest and forget me. Thank you, it was extremely funny to meet someone believing he had some basic linear algebra to teach me, after so many years. It makes me feel younger.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. We are a community intended to help each other by sharing knowledge. Here is not a Coliseum where we attack each other or inflates our egos. Take easy. I am not your opponent. Be respectful. I just downvoted because it is partially wrong. But I do not have felling about you. I do not even know who you are (and vise-versa). It seems you still have much things to learn.

Comment: My answer is not "partially wrong". I did my best to help you. I feel sorry for you.

Comment: Do not worry, I've already gone through it as well. The first reaction is to refuse it as much as you can, as you are doing here, just to protect the ego. After a while you will realize the you are wrong and matrices is, indeed, a linear transformation. That is normal (some people overpass this felling faster, actually...). Good luck :) But regarding your answer, I really appreciate it! Thank very much!

Comment: Take a look at this [Gilbert Strang's](http://students.aiu.edu/submissions/profiles/resources/onlineBook/Y5B7M4_Introduction_to_Linear_Algebra-_Fourth_Edition.pdf) statement: "Matrix multiplication $T (\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{A v}$ gives a linear transformation", at the beginning of the chapter 7. See? :)